# Variation on knapsack - minimum total value exceeding 'W'

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

Given the usual `n` sets of items (each unlimited, say), with weights and values:

```
w1, v1
w2, v2
...
wn, vn
```

and a target weight `W`, I need to choose items such that the total
weight is **at least** `W` and the total value is **minimized**.

This looks to me like a variation (or in some sense converse) of the
integer/unbounded knapsack problem.  Any help in formulating the DP algorithm
would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

let `TOT = w1 + w2 + ... + wn`.

In this answer I will describe a second bag. I'll denote the original as 'bag' and to the additional as 'knapsack'

Fill the bag with all elements, and start excluding elements from it, 'filling' up a **new knapsack** with size of at most `TOT-W`, with the highest possible value! You got yourself a regular knapsack problem, with same elements, and bag size of `TOT-W`.

**Proof:**

Assume you have best solution with k elements: `e_i1,e_i2,...,e_ik`, then the bag size is at least of size `W`, which makes the excluded items knapsack at most at size `TOT-W`.  Also, since the value of the knapsack is minimized for size `W`, the value of the excluded items is maximized for size `TOT-W`, because if it was not maximized, there would be a better bag of size at least `W`, with smaller value.

The other way around [assuming you have maximal excluded bag] is almost identical.

Comment: Came across the same problem, and this solution is so elegant. I'm impressed, really. Nice work.

Comment: Just a quick note, this solution does not work for unbounded knapsack problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure, but this might work. Consider the values to be the -ve of the values you have. The DP formulation would try to find max value for that weight which would be the least negative value in this case. Once you have a value, take a -ve of it for the final answer.