# minimizaton of 0/1 knapsack with additional constraint

Tags: algorithm

I have the same problem as here:
[Variation on knapsack - minimum total value exceeding 'W'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949705/variation-on-knapsack-minimum-total-value-exceeding-w)
with an **added constraint**.

Details:

We have a group of items, each item (i) has a weight (w_i) and a value (v_i) and a price(p_i). We have to select a subgroup of these items such that:

- minimize the total aggregate value

s.t.

1. total aggregate weight is at least *W*.
2. **total aggregate price is at most *P*.**

If we ignore the last constraint, this is equivalent of 0/1 knapsack problem and can be solved as *amit* mentioned in the question linked above. With the addition of last constraint is it still solvable using dynamic programming ?

Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Probably more suitable for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/. In any case you are clearly looking for homework solutions in a rude (and mostly lazy) way.

Comment: wrong guess Jack. Its not a homework, its simplified version of a real life problem and is not easy. If you think its straight forward, try solving it and I know you will be convinced.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a NP-hard problem, you just have to test all cases.

Comment: The Knapsack problem is also NP-hard, but it still has better solutions than brute-force.

Comment: @Thomash: This is not the original knappsack problem, but a knappsack problem with an additional constraint. Although I would guess it is still NP-hard, I cannot find a proof and neither did you present one, so we shouldn't be 100 percent sure. Adding additional constraints can change an NP-hard problem to become an element of P. At first sight this seems contra-intuitive since one would not suspect that adding an additional constraint can make a problem easier, but this is actually the case if the search-space becomes limited enough.

Comment: Brute force is not really an (feasible) option, because the actual problem relates to data centers that can actually have 1000s of different power configurations causing explosion of search space. I was searching for dynamic programming approach to it to atleast get pseudo polynomial time algorithm, but due to this extra constraint, I am having problem in determining the optimal substructure.

Answer (score 0):

An obvious solution is to use two variables in your dynamic programming state, W (current weight) and P (current price), such that m[W][P] gives the best value with those two parameters. This would give you an algorithm which runs in O(nP * sum of weights).

You might also want to consider the complementary solution (inverting W and P, as in amit's answer), depending on whether (sum of weights) * P or W * (sum of prices) is bigger.