# 0/1 Knapsack with integer values and irrational weights?

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

The standard 0/1 knapsack problem lends itself to a simple DP solution: with `n` distinct objects with irrational values, integer weights, and a max weight of `W`, make an `n x W` array `m` and let `m[i, j]` be the maximum value achievable with items 1 to `i` and a weight of at most `j`.

I'm trying to solve the problem where the weights are irrational but the values are rational. I'm told that there is an `O(nV)` solution, where `V` is the sum of all of the values. I want to say something like this: let `m` be an `n x V` array, and let `m[i, j]` be the minimum possible weight to achieve a value of at least `j` with items 1 to `i`. This would yield something like the following:

```
def knapsack(weights, values, max_weight):
    max_v = sum(values)
    m = [[0 for _ in range(max_v)] for _ in weights]

    for i in range(len(weights)):
        for j in range(max_v):
            if j < values[i]:
                m[i][j] = m[i - 1][j]
            else:
                m[i][j] = min(m[i - 1][j], weights[i] + m[i - 1][j - values[i]])

    for val, col in reversed(enumerate(zip(*m))):
        wt = min(col)
        if wt <= max_weight:
           return col

    return 0
```

But this doesn't work: cells like `m[0, 100]` get initialized with meaningless junk that propagates downward. I'm not sure how to solve this, and I can't find any info. It looks like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949705/variation-on-knapsack-minimum-total-value-exceeding-w) would provide an algorithm to fill each cell, but it would be too expensive to call for every single one.

Comment: is this a typo,"where the weights are irrational but the weights are rational", also could you give a small example ?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I also accidentally deleted some code from my broken solution.

Comment: @PM2Ring No, not at the moment, I don't think I used anything numpy specific? It's late, though, and I may have made a mistake.

Comment: Also, `m = [[0] * max_v] * len(weights)` probably doesn't do what you want it to do. Eg, `m=[[0]*5]*3;m[1][1]=7;print(m)` prints `[[0, 7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 0, 0, 0], [0, 7, 0, 0, 0]]`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/4014959 for details.

Comment: General case DP -- maybe you've seen this?  http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/Unbounded/Python_dynamic_programming

Comment: @PM2Ring Sorry, you're right, my mistake, on both counts.

Comment: @Paul None of those seem to handle non-integer weights, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change the meaning of `m` to the minimum weight for exactly the given value. We then want an initialization like

```
m = [[(float('inf') if j else 0) for j in range(max_v + 1)] for _ in range(len(weights) + 1)]
```

where I'm using positive infinity as a marker of infeasibility (I also fixed two off-by-one errors in the table size). Then the loop can look something like this (untested).

```
for i in range(len(weights)):
    for j in range(max_v + 1):
        if j >= values[i]:
            m[i + 1][j] = min(m[i][j], m[i][j - values[i]] + weights[i])
        else:
            m[i + 1][j] = m[i][j]
```

Then we have to adjust the output extraction to reflect the new definition of `m`.