# Find the length of smallest subarray which has sum greater than a given number

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I came across a problem on a coding contest which basically boils down to this.

Given an unsorted array with positive numbers find the length of the smallest subarray which has a sum greater than or equal to an input `sum`.

For `input : [14, 2, 10, 1, 1, 2, 1]`

And `sum = 10`output = 1 `[10]`

for `sum = 13`output = 1 `[14]`

for `sum = 15`output = 2 `[14, 2]`

There will be a lot of queries to answer in the range of `1 to 10^5`.

My approach.

Build an array of the same length as the input where `array[i]` will be the maximum sum of a subarray of size `i`. This can be done in `O(N * N)` time and `O(N)` space

So now we have an `array` with increasing `sum` so we can use binary search to find the smallest length that can satisfy the particular input sum.

so if there were `q` queries it would run in `O(q * log(N))` time.

I'm not sure how feasible this solution is or if there is a better solution than this. Since I couldn't test it out on that online judge and the problem isn't available now.

Is there a better solution to this in terms of time and space complexity.

Follow up:

What if the given input can be changed later. How do you have such situations where the input can be updated.

Comment: According to me that's the optimal approach for this problem, it can't get better than this

Comment: depends on constraints like maximum N, maximum value of each element, if there is a constraint on sum of whole array...

Comment: This sounds like knapsack https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7949705/variation-on-knapsack-minimum-total-value-exceeding-w

Answer (score 0):

I'd use prefix array for this.

Prefix array - is additional array for a

pr_a[0] = a[0]
pr_a[i] = pr_a[i-1] + a[i]

Prefix array has O(n) precalculation and O(1) calculation.

Write function max_window(pr_a, k), which'd find subarray with maximal sum on it.

```
def max_w(pr_a, k):
    m = pr_a[k-1]
    for i in range(1, len(pr_a) - k + 1): 
        m = max(m, pr_a[i + k - 1] - pr_a[i-1])
    return m
```

This will find sum. I think you understand how this function can find indexes.

Then binary search on answer.

And we have O(q * n * log(n))

Actually if you want to change an array after precalculation, you can use [Segment Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)