# PHP find cheapest permutation

Tags: php, algorithm, math, search

I have multiple products that all have sizes and I need to find the cheapest configuration that meets the minimum required size.

For example, John needs a minimum of 10 litres of storage - it can be more, but not less.

There are 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L and 10L options (but this can change).

As an example, it might be cheaper to get:

- 1x10L container OR
- 2x5L containers OR
- 1x2L, 1x3L and 1x5L OR
- 4x3L (this one is over 10 L, but it is still possible that it will be cheaper)

So far I've tried looping over and over up to 4 times (because typically the maximum requirement will be 40 L), but in some cases I am running out of memory, and it doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing it.

```
// Size is in mL

$available_containers = [
[
  'id' => 22700,
  'price' => 1190,
  'size' => 2000,
],
[
  'id' => 22701,
  'price' => 1245,
  'size' => 3000,
],
[
  'id' => 22702,
  'price' => 1415,
  'size' => 4000,
],
[
  'id' => 22715,
  'price' => 12300,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22706,
  'price' => 1740,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22703,
  'price' => 1510,
  'size' => 5000,
],
[
  'id' => 22707,
  'price' => 1790,
  'size' => 6000,
],
[
  'id' => 22704,
  'price' => 1770,
  'size' => 6000,
],
[
  'id' => 22708,
  'price' => 2215,
  'size' => 7000,
],
[
  'id' => 22705,
  'price' => 2195,
  'size' => 8200,
],
[
  'id' => 22709,
  'price' => 2660,
  'size' => 8200,
],
[
  'id' => 22710,
  'price' => 2799,
  'size' => 10000,
],
[
  'id' => 22711,
  'price' => 2910,
  'size' => 12500,
],
[
  'id' => 22712,
  'price' => 3260,
  'size' => 15000,
],
[
  'id' => 22713,
  'price' => 4130,
  'size' => 20000,
],
[
  'id' => 22714,
  'price' => 3770,
  'size' => 27000,
]
];

$required_size = 8; // Can change.
$container_install = 5;

foreach ( $available_containers as $v ){
  foreach ( $available_containers as $v2 ){
    foreach ($available_containers as $v3 ) {
      foreach ( $available_containers as $v4 ){

        $all_configs = [
          [
            'size' => $v['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'],
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $container_install,
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'] + $v3['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'], $v3['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $v3['price'] + $container_install + $container_install,
          ],
          [
            'size' => $v['size'] + $v2['size'] + $v3['size'] + $v4['size'],
            'configuration' => [ $v['size'], $v2['size'], $v3['size'], $v4['size'] ],
            'price' => $v['price'] + $v2['price'] + $v3['price'] + $v4['price'] + $container_install + $container_install + $container_install,
          ],
        ];


        foreach ( $all_configs as $c ){
          if ( $c['size'] >= $required_size ){
            $configuration[] = array(
              'configuration' => $c['configuration'],
              'size' => $c['size'],
              'price' => $c['price'],
            );
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


// Sort by price.
$sorted_configs = array_sort($configuration, 'price', SORT_ASC); // This function simply sorts all permutations by price
```

Comment: n x n x n x n is not a good complexity. you may try this recursive function https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm

Comment: What you should do is loop once, with probably a while loop, then use  division to get the number of times it goes into each one (in order of largest to smallest)  Subtract that value out, and do it again.  Reducing the original value each time.

Comment: This seems to be more of a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @JosuaMarcelChrisano - I'll have a look.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - I'm no mathematical genius - just a programmer haha. Can you clarify with an example?

Comment: `$available_containers` is not a valid array, it's some weird combination of print_r and something else.  And how does this `[size] => 5000` compare to {n}L

Comment: @Jeff - I haven't used codereview - how is it different to Stackoverflow?

Comment: Thanks @ArtisticPhoenix - it was a mix of both. I have edited it now.

Comment: SO is for specific coding problems you can't solve ("This should work, because ..., but gives me this unexpected result"), whereas codereview is more for "This code works, but doesn't look right. Is there a better way?"

Comment: @Mando - What I was thinking wont work anyway, you need to find all combinations, then figure the price for each one, then choose the cheapest one, I was thinking fit the fewest number of containers.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the size is in mL

Comment: Sounds a bit like the "set cover problem" (NP complete) -- although you don't need the whole universe, just something that adds to >= 10L. Not sure if that makes it different or not. Or maybe the knapsack problem (https://stackoverflow.com/q/7949705/65387). I was never good at these proofs.

Comment: Hmm thanks @mpen - I haven't heard of  those things before, but I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are some points can make these loops light weight. This problem must be solved with divide and conquer approach.

1. Create a subarray, because you don't need whole array, a new subarray from 1L to 10L only.
2. The sub array should be sorted in order by price, from lowest to height.
3. If and only if the lowest price which represent in first index can only bought one times, `break` the loop.
4. Otherwise, you should have a list which take the output when you already looping.